# Window.open() opens url concatinated with my website's url

Tags: javascript, html

example

```
window.open("www.google.com");
```

Opens www.mywebsite.com/www.google.com

Why is it doing that and how can I make it open google.com?

Comment: Without a leading protocol (`https:`, for example), the URL is assumed to be relative.

Comment: You do not have a protocol defined for the url you want to pop up. In that case relative specification is taken in to account, which mashes up URLS as @RobW suggested. Provide a protocol like http or https.

Comment: To add to what [**RobW**](http://stackoverflow.com/users/938089/rob-w) said, here is also a handy reference to the [**window.open documentation**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/window.open) which has an interesting section on usability and when-why not to resort to use `windows.open` in several scenarios. Thought you might find that a handy reference to have in general :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try using a full url instead of a short one:

```
window.open("http://www.google.com");
```

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
window.open("http://www.google.com");
```

may it will help you